# PowerShell to remove row from CSV

Tags: powershell

I run a script internally to fetch the SystemName and its model on my organization LAN Segment. Following is the sample CSV file.

```
"SystemName","Model"
"DELL-10110","DELL Optiplex"
"DELL-10111","DELL Optiplex"
"Lenovo-30119","Lenovo ThinkCentre"
"DELL-10112","DELL Optiplex"
"HP-21011","HP Prodesk"
"HP-21012","HP Prodesk"
```

And I run another Powershell script to import the CSV file and remove entire row if the SystemName contains *HP*. But the output CSV file is still having HP systems.

```
$DATA = Import-CSv C:\IT\Inventory.csv | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SystemName = $_.SystemName
        Model = $_.Model
    }
}
$DATA | Where-Object {$_.SystemName -ne "*HP*"} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\IT\Inventory-New.csv
```

Comment: Use `-notlike '*HP*'`, not `-ne`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Theo mentioned, the problem is definitely in the comparison operator `-ne`. @Theo's comment is an acceptable solution, but I'd point out there's a lot of unnecessary stuff going on here.  `Import-Csv` already outputs PSCustomObjects, there's no reason to create new objects inside a `ForEach-Object` loop.  Once that's realized you can condense this to a single pipeline like:

```
    Import-CSv 'C:\IT\Inventory.csv' | 
    Where-Object{ $_.SystemName -notmatch '^HP' } |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\IT\Inventory-New.csv'
```

Note: Even if you needed objects with only a subset of the original properties I'd use `Select-Object` before resorting to creating new objects.  `Select-Object` also outputs PSCustomObjects.

In above sample I used `-notmatch` with the RegEx anchor `^`. The Where clause effectively means where doesn't start with "HP".  However, that's just for demonstration sake. `-notlike "*HP*"` or `"HP*"` may work just as well all depending on your data.